# Can't set permissions in Graph API Explorer tool

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

There no permissions appear in the permissions list else user_payment_tokens[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FBkm.jpg)

I'm trying set permissions to get other fields like posts, comments or email, but i can't find permission in permission list, what's wrong?